# How to remediate Path Manipulation in Java Code

Tags: java, security

Controller class -
Get method calls a downloadPdf

ServiceImpl class -
downloadPdf (fileName)
{
pdfFilePath = path + "/PDF/"
**FileInputStream fs = new  FileInputStream (new File(pdfFilePath + fileName))**
}

Highlighted code is throwing Path Manipulation vulnerability, how to fix this ?
Approach I was thinking - To getCanonicalPath of pdfFilePath or fileName or both and then compares it with expected path ?

some validatePath method which I can use to fix it.

Comment: Which paths do you want to allow? You probably don't want your users to call `downloadPdf("../../../../../../../etc/passwd")`. If your file names follow a pattern, you could only allow those. Or forbid anything that's not a letter or digit, as well as two consecutive dots (but allow a single dot for the file extension).

Comment: This is really more of a logical issue since you can only mitigate this by *not* assigning the sort of stuff @knittl has just mentioned, so it depends on the variables more than the code in which they are used. Better code might look more like `Path pdfFile = Path.of(path).resolve("PDF").resolve(fileName);InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(pdfFile);`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.